# How to Send data between two ESP8266 WiFi modules

Tags: at-command

I have two boards with a micro(ATmega8) on each and a module(ESP8266) connected to each micro. How can I transfer data between these two boards(without a router)? In other words, what are the AT commands that must be written for each micro to be connected?
I also use the Basic language in Bascom for programming, as below:

Client:

```
Print "AT+CWMODE=3"
Print "AT+CWJAP="test","1111111111""
Print "AT+CIPMUX=1"
Print "AT+CIPSTART=2,"TCP","192.168.4.1",222"  \\link type error
Print "AT+CIPSEND=0,1"
print "A"
```

Server:

```
Print "AT+CWMODE=3"
Print "AT+CWSAP="test","1111111111",1,4"
Print "AT+CIPMUX=1"
Print "AT+CIPSERVER=1,222"
Print "AT+CIFSR"
```

What's going wrong? What is your idea?

Comment: What is the model name of the wifi module connected to ESP8266? Can you link the AT command manual of that module, so that we can understand together what's going wrong?

Comment: I mean the ATmega8 is connected directly to the ESP8266 (no interface module). My problem is in line 4 of the Client program(link type error).

Comment: This link is " ESP8266 AT Instruction Set" : https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf